# Inheritance and dependency Injection in Angular

Tags: angular, inheritance, dependency-injection

I would like to create a component(childComponent) that inherits from another(parentComponent).

The thing is the parentComponent have injected a lot of services and we are adding more, constantly.

Besides, the childComponent needs another service that It's not present in the parentComponent. Then we need to add a constructor with super and inject this service.

How can inject all services from the parent in the child but in a way that all are included at once? Doing this we avoid changes in the childComponent because if you add a new service, It's automatically injected into his child.

I tried this but it doesn't work properly

```js
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {MyServiceA} from './myServiceA';
import {MyServiceB} from './myServiceB';
import {MyServiceC} from './myServiceC';

export class ParentComponent {
  protected myServiceA:MyServiceA;
  protected myServiceB:MyServiceB;
  protected myServiceC:MyServiceC;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    this.myServiceA = injector.get(MyServiceA);
    this.myServiceB = injector.get(MyServiceB);
    this.myServiceC = injector.get(MyServiceC);
  }
}

export ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  constructor(
    private anotherService: AnotherService,
    injector: Injector
  ) {
    super(injector);

    this.myServiceA.JustCallSomeMethod();
    this.myServiceB.JustCallAnotherMethod();
    this.myServiceC.JustOneMoreMethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you even referencing ChildComponent in a template somewhere?

Comment: Hi @alsami, yes I have 2 different templates one for each component. And I call one for one view and the other in another view.
I get an error that in the childComponent can't get all parameters

Comment: Please provide the errors.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ChildComponent: (?).

Comment: Did you add the `@Injectable()` decorator to your service ?

Comment: Yes, It's working fine for the Parent Component

Comment: Maybe try creating a reproducible example on stackbliz.com so that it is easier for people to help

Comment: You can make an object of services and send it by @Input() decorator, but I prefer use the contructor its easy `constructor(private serviceobject:ServiceInjectClass)`